# Printing only string

Tags: java, string

Dear All,
I have 2 input string 1)stack,over,flow 2)stack/over,flow,com
I would like to print only strings(without special char)from the above 2 input
for 1st input i used below function but for 2nd input i dont know how to process it.Pls give me solution.

```
st = new StringTokenizer("stack,over,flow", ",");
       while (st.hasMoreTokens())
        {
            String token = st.nextToken();
           System.out.println("token = " + token);
        }
```

output:

```
stack
over
flow
```

Comment: Can you format the code so that it is readable? Click "Edit" and use the formatting tips shown on the right side of the page (after you click "edit")

Comment: SOrry i am new to stackoverflow that's why i posted like this.Hereafter i will post my question correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you define what you mean by a *special char*? Do you mean "only alphanumeric characters"?

If you want to remove all possible special characters and leave only alphanumeric characters, then you can use the following:

```
s = s.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "");
```

If you want to print them one by one:

```
s = s.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "/");
String[] splitString = s.split("/");
for(String str:splitString)
{
   System.out.println(str);
}
```

**EIDT:**
Since you asked: the above code uses the [enhanced for loop](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) (also called the for-each loop) introduced by java 5.
Using the 'normal' for loop, this is:

```
s = s.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "/");
String[] splitString = s.split("/");
for(int i=0; i<splitString.length(); i++)
{
   String str = splitString[i];
   System.out.println(str);
}
```

Also:

> `StringTokenizer` is a legacy class
>   that is retained for compatibility
>   reasons although its use is
>   discouraged in new code. It is
>   recommended that anyone seeking this
>   functionality use the `split` method
>   of `String` or the `java.util.regex`
>   package instead.

(from the [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html))

Comment: Can you pls tell me what is the str value in for loop.

Comment: str is the loop variable. The code i mentioned uses the enhanced for loop of java 5. I have edited the answer to add the 'normal' for loop

Comment: Cannot invoke length() on the array type String[] i got this error while compiling your edited code.

Comment: String s="stack/over,flow,com";
        i add this line only with your edited code.

Comment: That is not very difficult, you could have tried yourself: instead of `splitString.length();` use `splitString.length;`

Answer (score 0):

You need to format your question better, it's hard to follow. But if I read it correctly,

```
st = new StringTokenizer("stack,over,flow", ",/");
```

Should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you in both the cases:

```
   String[] strArr=yourString.split("[/,]");
   for(String str:strArr)
   {
     System.out.println(str);
   }
```